# Invert if statement with pipes

Tags: bash, if-statement

I want to add a command to my `.bash_profile` that runs a script if it's not already running. Below is my attempt.

```
if ps ax | grep reminder.py | grep -v grep;
  echo 'i want to get rid of this line'
then
  python /Users/Jesse/Dropbox/reminder/reminder.py &
fi
```

I can't figure out the syntax for inverting the if statement.

I tried a bunch of stuff similar to this:

```
if ! ps ax | grep reminder.py | grep -v grep
then
  python /Users/Jesse/Dropbox/reminder/reminder.py &
fi
```

None of my attempts were successful.

I'm running on macOS if that's relevant.

Comment: You can do `ps ax | grep reminder.py | grep -v grep || python /Users/Jesse/Dropbox/reminder/reminder.py & `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash, `!` means negate.  So, without changing anything else, you could use:

```
if ! ps ax | grep reminder.py | grep -v grep
then
  python /Users/Jesse/Dropbox/reminder/reminder.py &
fi
```

But you probably want to eliminate the grep output, so use `-q` for quiet:

```
if ! ps ax | grep reminder.py | grep -q -v grep
then
  python /Users/Jesse/Dropbox/reminder/reminder.py &
fi
```

The pipeline can be simplified if we are just more clever about the regex that we give grep (Hat tip: [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson)):

```
if ! ps ax | grep -q "reminder[.]py"
then
  python /Users/Jesse/Dropbox/reminder/reminder.py &
fi
```

The above works because `reminder[.]py` does *not* match `reminder[.]py` but is does match `reminder.py`.  You can test this on the command line:

```
$ echo 'reminder[.]py' | grep 'reminder[.]py'
$ echo 'reminder.py' | grep 'reminder[.]py'
reminder.py
```

As you can see, only the second command above shows a match.

Further, if its available on your system, `pgrep` eliminates the need for a pipeline:

```
if ! pgrep -f reminder.py >/dev/null
then
  python /Users/Jesse/Dropbox/reminder/reminder.py &
fi
```

For those who prefer one liners, the above simplifies to:

```
pgrep -f reminder.py >/dev/null || python /Users/Jesse/Dropbox/reminder/reminder.py &
```

In the above `||` is logical-or.  The command following `||` is executed *only if* the command that precedes it fails (exits a non-zero return code).

Comment: If you don't have pgrep, you can use `ps ax | grep -q "reminder[.]py" and omit the `grep -q -v grep`. The square brackets prevent `grep` from matching itself, and also have the benefit of preventing it from matching something other than a period at that position (since in an RE, "`.`" matches any single character).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Excellent.  I just added the square-bracket trick to the answer.

Comment: Let's get rid of the if , then, fi, and !  , too.  Try this ```pgrep -f reminder.py >/dev/null || python /Users/Jesse/Dropbox/reminder/reminder.py & ``` or if pgrep is not available:  ```ps ax | grep -q "reminder[.]py" || python /Users/Jesse/Dropbox/reminder/reminder.py &```

Comment: @Mark Very good.  I updated the answer with a version using `||`.